# Permission denied issues when use rvm install ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, permissions, installation, rvm

I searched lots of contents, but still can not find what's the reason, I'm sure the rvm folder permission should be right.

```
$ rvm get stable

A RVM version 1.20.13 (master) is installed yet 1.20.13 () is loaded.
Please do one of the following:
  * 'rvm reload'
  * open a new shell
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for auto reload with msg.
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for silent auto reload.
```

And check the rvm version:

```
$ rvm --version

rvm 1.20.13 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Then install ruby 2.0.0:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0

mkdir: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195: Permission denied
mkdir: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195: Permission denied

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p195.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p195, this may take a while depending on your connection...

mkdir: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_32045: Permission denied
mkdir: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195: Permission denied
tee: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1370079408_extract.log: No such file or directory
tee: /Users/xudannie/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1370079408_extract.log: No such file or directory
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p195 to /Users/xudannie/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p195....

Error running '__rvm_package_extract /Users/xudannie/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.0.0-p195.tar.bz2 /Users/xudannie/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_32045',
please read /Users/xudannie/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1370079408_extract.log
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I'm just start to learning ROR, so there is too much problems I need to face.

Hope your help!

Answer (score 4):

Try runing `sudo rvm install 2.0.0` and if this doesn't work just run `sudo chmod a+rw -R ~/.rvm` and then `rvm install 2.0.0` once again.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R a+rw ~/.rvm`